# Botão Voltar e Teclado android

Tags: android

Estou na verdade com dois problemas:

- O *BackPressed* ele retira o teclado e *buga* uma linha de comando, não sei o por quê. Praticamente ele ignora o `adappLista.notifyDataSetChanged()` e não faz a modificação na minha lista do `recyclerview`.
- O outro problema envolve o teclado que passa de numérico para alfanumérico e ainda fica bloqueado. Não dá para utilizá-lo.

```
if (lista.get(posicaoview).isLinhaselecionada()) {                                
lista.get(posicaoview).setLinhaselecionada(false);
adappLista.notifyDataSetChanged();}
```

Comment: coloca o código da activity aqui e imagens que retratam o ocorrido (se puder)

Comment: Na verdade estava depurando o código e vi que o problema está no EditText quando ele é recyclado dá esse bug no teclado. Testei apenas com o EditText inserido e ocorre o mesmo problema sempre quando é reciclado